# Text size increment during Heap initialization

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above program using gcc on a 32-bit linux machine. I then ran the size command on the executable. The results I got were as follows:

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1415        544       8    1967     7af ./a.out
```

Then i am adding the malloc call

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char)*4); //stored in heap
  return 0;
}
```

I then ran the size command on the executable. The results I got were as follows:

```
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1504        600       8    2112     840 ./a.out
```

How the malloc call affect the text and also data size

Comment: I'd guess that you create the first reference to glibc, which adds some stubs that load the library (text increase beyond the few bytes for the function call) and adds the global offset table and procedure linkage table (increase in data).

Comment: By including malloc it is placed inside the text segment, and by allocating data into heap your data segment grow up. As expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you asking? What results did you expect?

You added more lines of code, therefore the `text` segment got bigger.
You added new `ptr` variable - therefore the `data` segment got bigger.

Comment: It's a function call, a `push`, a `call`, and a `sub` instruction, that should be much less than 90 bytes. Also the `ptr` is stack-allocated, so it does not count towards the data segment.

Answer (score 2):

I compiled the example on an x86-64 machine with `gcc -m32` (GCC 9.3.0). The numbers I get are slightly different:

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1408     292       4    1704     6a8 a.out
1509     296       4    1809     711 a.out2
```

The differences are mainly caused by dynamic linking infrastructure because you have added a new symbol reference:

- The dynamic symbol table `.dynsym` gets a new entry (+16 bytes)
- The accompanying string table `.dynstr` gets a new entry for the name of the function, `malloc` plus a NUL byte (+7 bytes)
- The symbol version table `.gnu.version` grows (+2 bytes)
- There is a new relocation added to `.rel.plt` to fixup the procedure linkage table with the address of `malloc` (+8 bytes)
- The procedure linkage table `.plt` gains an entry (+16 bytes)
- The text segment `.text` itself grows mainly because main needs some instructions to save and restore registers before and after the call to `malloc` (+32 bytes)
- The unwind table `.eh_frame` grows (+20 bytes)
- A part of the global offset table `.got.plt` gets an additional entry to facilitate getting the address of `malloc` (+4 bytes)

All but the last one are counted towards the size of the text in the output of `size`, totalling 101 bytes more text and 4 bytes more data, as expected.

You can get the breakdown by segment by using `objdump -h a.out`.